# BizTalk schema development issue with element Occurrences

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, schema-design

Please find the below XML format, for which I'm trying to build a Schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?ORX ORXHEADER="200" VERSION="201" SECURITY="NONE" OLDFILEUID="NONE" NEWFILEUID="NONE" ?>
<ORX>
  <NONSIGNONMSGSRQV1>
    <NONSONRQ>
      <CLIENT>123456765</CLIENT>
      <ID>arout_int</ID>
      <USERPASS>IM_Developer</USERPASS>
      <LANGUAGE>ENG</LANGUAGE>
      <APPID>WASSUP</APPID>
      <APPOVER>1</APPOVER>
    </NONSONRQ>
  </NONSIGNONMSGSRQV1> 
  <NONVERMSGSRQV1>
    <NONEMPLOYERHISTTRNRQ>
      <COOKIE>1234576540</COOKIE>
      <COOKIETAN>12345612340</COOKIETAN> 
      <BILLINGO1>45674567890</BILLINGO1> 
      <BILLINGO2>1245673567890</BILLINGO2> 
      <PURPOSE>
        <CODE>PROGRAM</CODE>
      </PURPOSE> 
      <EMPLOYERHISTRQ>
        <EMPLOYEEID>123004567</EMPLOYEEID>
      </EMPLOYERHISTRQ>
  </NONEMPLOYERHISTTRNRQ>
            <ANNUALCOMPCOLLECTION>
                <ANNUALCOMP>
                    <YEAR>2002</YEAR>
                    <BASE>9633.45</BASE>
                    <OVERTIME>268.29</OVERTIME>
                    <OTHER>7732.4</OTHER>
                    <TOTAL>17634.14</TOTAL>
                </ANNUALCOMP>
                <ANNUALCOMP>
                    <YEAR>2001</YEAR>
                    <BASE>12035.72</BASE>
                    <OVERTIME>390.93</OVERTIME>
                    <COMMISSION>5840.48</COMMISSION>
                    <BONUS>3234.28</BONUS>
                    <OTHER>8974.43</OTHER>
                    <TOTAL>21010.15</TOTAL>
                </ANNUALCOMP>
                <ANNUALCOMP>
                    <YEAR>2000</YEAR>
                    <BASE>10938.47</BASE>
                    <OVERTIME>25.89</OVERTIME>
                    <OTHER>9389.62</OTHER>
                    <TOTAL>20353.98</TOTAL>
                </ANNUALCOMP>
      </ANNUALCOMPCOLLECTION>    
  </NONVERMSGSRQV1>
</ORX>
```

If you see chich record -> ANNUALCOMPCOLLECTION -> ANNUALCOMP -> **COMMISSION & BONUS** Elements, are constantly not repeating.

Due to this reason, my schema validation Instance throwing the warning as below

> error BEC2004: The element 'ANNUALCOMP' has invalid child element 'OTHER'. List of possible elements expected: 'OVERTIME, COMMISSION'.
>
> error BEC2004: The element 'ANNUALCOMP' has invalid child element 'OTHER'. List of possible elements expected: 'OVERTIME, COMMISSION'.

What kind of properties I have to set to achieve this validating correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by below settings,

1. Changed the property from Group Occurrences to Single record record Occurrences type
2. On Each element I set the min-0 & Max-Occurance-*,

My schema got validated instance.